# Google App Engine/Cloud SQL/Django syncdb database backend error

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I've been successfully able to run syncdb's on my django project for the past weeks, but something must have happened and I'm not sure what.

I always get this error:

```
 No module named google.appengine.ext.django.backends.rdbms.base
```

I'm not sure why it's just kind of started.  Shortly after getting this error, I tried updating my project on app engine and was prompted to download a new app engine launcher SDK, which I have done, but this error still exists.  Not sure if maybe something is wrong with my PYTHONPATH?

Comment: Any updates on this? Did you manage to figure out if you made any changes to your app which might have caused this, or did it stop happening?

Answer (score 0):

From your description, this sounds like it could possibly be an issue, not intended behaviour. It sounds crazy, but perhaps something changed with the default Django installation. I suggest you attach a basic reproducing app to a new issue thread in the [Public Issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-appengine/issues/list)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to authorize your IP address. If that doesn't work, try using the standard MySQL driver instead of the Google App Engine one as described [in our docs.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/djangohttps://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django?hl=en#usage)